# List operation for beginner Usage of #1 and #2 (in stead of using for loop)

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have trouble using list operation of #1 and #2. Could you please tell me how to make it?

I prepared the list as below,

```
np = 10;
r = RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {np, 2}];
the = RandomReal[{0, 360}, np];
points = {r[[#]][[1]] + Cos[the[[#]] Degree], 
r[[#]][[2]] + Sin[the[[#]] Degree]} & /@ Range[np];
join1 = Join[r, points] (* Joining the list of r and points *)
```

Then, what I want is to make 3 sets of join1, without using for loop,so

```
n = 3;

listR = Table[RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {np, 2}], n]
listThe = Table[RandomReal[{0, 360}, np], n]
(* I tried to make these 3 times and conbine, so I tried like followings *)
points3 = {listR[[#1]][[#2]][[1]] + 
Cos[listThe[[#1]][[#2]] Degree], 
listR[[#1]][[#2]][[2]] + Sin[listThe[[#1]][[#2]] Degree]} &[Range[n], Range[np]]
```

However, error occurs and I have no answer for it.

At last, I want to get list of joining listR and points3, so it might be like

```
join2 = Join[listR[[#1]][[#2]], points3[[#1]][[#2]]] & /@ [Range[n], 
Range[np]];
```

But I have no confidence. I wonder someone would kindly help me how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually much closer than you think. I will give you the short and long ways to go about it. The longer way looks more complex, but trust me when I say that once you get accustomed to it, you will not go back from it!

The problem is that you are trying to use slots (`#1,#2`) in a generalised way to create higher order `Table`, which, to my knowledge, you cannot do. You could however just use `Table`!!

## Using `Table`, the bread & butter of lists

I would only make the minor change in your code on points3

```
points3T=Table[{listR[[i]][[j]][[1]] + Cos[listThe[[i]][[j]] Degree], 
  listR[[i]][[j]][[2]] + Sin[listThe[[i]][[j]] Degree]}, {i, 1, 
  n}, {j, 1, np}]
```

This immediately solves your problem (i believe), and then it is just a matter of joining the lists as you see it fit.

I would suggest that you have a look at the following method using its own function, as shown below:

---

## Creating a dedicated function

### `MapThread`

MapThread is a very powerful tool and well suited for what you are trying to do. It is also keeping your code a bit neater and easier to read. I will use it on your simpler, first example to convince you that it can do (in principle!) what you ultimately desire.

```
pointsMT=MapThread[{#1[[1]] + Cos[#2 Degree], #1[[2]] + Sin[#2 Degree]} &, {r, 
  the}]; (* using MapThread rather than a nested 1D Table *)
pointsMT==points (* this is to convince yourself that it works *)
```

---

### Use `Module`/`Block` to create smaller functions

This is good practice in general as it once again keeps your code readable and easy to scale, modify etc.. Here is an example of me using a `Block` to create a function that performs the threading once, and then I apply the function to the n=3 case by using `MapThread` once again.

```
Clear[threader]
threader[r_, the_] := Block[{points},
  (* this is a function that takes two lists, "r" and "the", 
  and then spits out the polar coordinates *)
  points = 
   MapThread[{#1[[1]] + Cos[#2 Degree], #1[[2]] + 
       Sin[#2 Degree]} &, {r, the}]
  ]



 points3MT= MapThread[threader[#1, #2] &, {listR, listThe}]
```

I would normally change the variable names within `threader` to make it more easy for the reader to know what r and the actually mean when using the function, but I kept it here the same for simplicity.

You can convince yourself that this works as expected by checking with the previous Table function:

```
points3T==points3MT
```

Joining the two parts can be done very easily using MapThread, once again!

```
MapThread[Join[#1, #2] &, {listR, points3T}]
```

---

The good part about the `Block` and `Module` tools is that you can make it so that your data generation (`RandomReal`) and combination as well as Joining, all happen within that same block. If you prefer to have a separate function to generate the data and another for the grouping and joining, it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you So Much for teaching me, it's very kind of you, I'm really impressed!! I haven't get an answer like this before, it's so introductory and very easy to understand. I'm so grateful to you. And yes, this is reall what I wanted to do. Now I could successfully get data, which I desired. Also, owing to your explaination, I got tips of "Block", too. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome :)
And the documentation is always your friend.

Comment: It’s so nice of you to give me warm-hearted reply! I'm so lucky to get your instruction.